# pynput on_press triggerd by own keyboard.press

Tags: python, listener, pynput

Like described in the titel, the function `on_press` of the pynput listener gets triggerd by it's own keypress.

I tried doing several things, like adding a boolean that makes it so that when the code itselfs run the keypress or keyrelease, it doesn't print or press the key, and even added a massive delay, but none of this works.

The code:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

k = Controller()

randomVar = True

def on_press(key):
    global randomVar
    if randomVar:
        print(key)
        randomVar = False
        k.press(key)
        time.sleep(0.45)
        randomVar = True

def on_release(key):
    global randomVar
    if randomVar:
        print(key)
        randomVar = False
        k.release(key)
        time.sleep(0.45)
        randomVar = True


# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(suppress=True, on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    try:
        listener.join()
    except Exception as e:
        print('{0} was pressed'.format(e.args[0]))
```

Expected output when I push `d`

```
'd'
'd'
```

Actual output:

```
'd'
'd'
'd'
'd'
'd'
'd'
...
```

EDIT:
I also tried just putting everything in on_press, but this gives the same result:

```
def on_press(key):
    global randomVar
    if randomVar:
        print(key)
        randomVar = False
        k.press(key)
        k.release(key)
        time.sleep(0.45)
        randomVar = True

def on_release(key):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a terrible way of doing this, but currently after struggling for hours, the only thing I could come up with. It stops the listener and then pressed the key, and then starts the listener again, making it a loop of stopping and starting the listener, which is very suboptimal

I would love to hear from people how this could've been differently, but for now, this is my only solution:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

k = Controller()

def on_press(key):
    global listener

    print(str(key))
    listener.stop()

def on_release(key):
    pass

while True:
    listener = keyboard.Listener(suppress=True, on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
    listener.start()
    listener.join()
    k.press("l")
    k.release("l")
```